# Trading a day too late

Tags: pine-script

this is my first post for help here. I have pulled together a simple strategy that looks for gaps (among other criteria). My problem is the strategy seems to trade a day late. I have a picture that shows the issue fairly simply.

Here you will see in the red circle the strategy did not open a trade (even though it met the criteria, or so I think) on the day with the green inverted hammer, instead the day after.

[image]

Does anyone see what I am doing wrong?

```
//@version=3
// Define strategy settings
strategy(title="Gap Down and Oversold", overlay=true,
     pyramiding=0, initial_capital=2000,
     default_qty_type=strategy.percent_of_equity,
     default_qty_value=20,
     commission_type=strategy.commission.cash_per_order,
     commission_value=0, slippage=2,
     calc_on_every_tick=true)

gapDownSize = input(title="Gap Size %", type=float, defval=-10, step=1)
length = input( 14 )
overSold = input( 36 )
price = close
vrsi = rsi(price, length)
longLossPerc = input(title="Long Stop Loss (%)",
     type=float, minval=0.0, step=0.1, defval=7.5) / 100
longProfitPerc = input(title="Long Take Profit (%)",
     type=float, minval=0.0, step=0.1, defval=15) / 100
SMA1 = input(title="SMA1 >", type=integer, defval=20, step=1)
SMA2 = input(title="SMA2", type=integer, defval=10, step=1)
s1 = sma(close, SMA1)
s2 = sma(close, SMA2)
     
// Configure backtest start date with inputs
startDate = input(title="Start Date", type=integer,
     defval=1, minval=1, maxval=31)
startMonth = input(title="Start Month", type=integer,
     defval=1, minval=1, maxval=12)
startYear = input(title="Start Year", type=integer,
     defval=2020, minval=1800, maxval=2100)
     
// See if bar's close time is before end date
beforeEndDate = (time >= timestamp(syminfo.timezone,
     startYear, startMonth, startDate, 0, 0))
     
// Calculate strategy values
gapSize    = ((open - close[1]) / close[1]) * 100
RSIOverSold = (vrsi < overSold)
Trend = s1 > s2

// Determine long trading conditions
enterLong = (gapSize < gapDownSize) and RSIOverSold and Trend

// Determine SL and PT
longStopPrice  = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 - longLossPerc)
longExitPrice  = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 + longProfitPerc)

// Highlight gap trigger level
//plot(series=gapDownSize, color=green, transp=70,
//     title="Gap Down Size [Long Entry]")

// Highlight long and short signals
//bgColour = enterLong ? green :
//     na
//bgcolor(color=bgColour, transp=85)

// Submit entry orders
if (beforeEndDate and enterLong)
    strategy.entry(id="EL", long=true)

// Submit exit orders
if (strategy.position_size > 0)
    strategy.exit(id="XL", limit=longExitPrice,stop=longStopPrice)
```

Answer (score 0):

With a strategy, trades are entered at the open of the next bar by default. You might want to set `process_orders_on_close` to true.

```
strategy("My Strategy", overlay=true,process_orders_on_close=true)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That was it. :)